# How many subdomains can I have with a B1 tier app service plan?

Tags: azure

If I purchase the B1 tier for an App Service, does that mean I could have both a custom domain, domain.com, and subdomain sub.domain.com, on a single App Service, or would I instead need to purchase a higher tier such as S1?

Do I need to purchase a separate App Service for each subdomain, or can I put multiple subdomains on a single Azure App Service?

Please note that I have been researching the above and have found these links but the answer is not clear to me:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-hosting-plans
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/azure/virtual-machines/dedicated-hosts?WT.mc_id=Portal-Microsoft_Azure_Support
- [https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/23598/how-to-bind-multiple-custom-domains-and-redirect-to-azure-web-app#:~:text=You%20can%20add%20as%20many,to%20different%20sites%20in%20Sitecore](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/23598/how-to-bind-multiple-custom-domains-and-redirect-to-azure-web-app#:%7E:text=You%20can%20add%20as%20many,to%20different%20sites%20in%20Sitecore).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like I can have multiple subdomains using Deployment Slots, where I need at least the Standard Tier S1 or higher for this feature:

https://stackify.com/azure-deployment-slots/